# Create Group (Distribution group) and add members EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS(Exchange Web Services) C#.

I want to create/modify Distribution group like the follow:
[image]

With EWS API.

I can to get the group and its users:

```
ExpandGroupResults myGroupMembers = service.ExpandGroup("Test@mydomain.com");

foreach (EmailAddress address in myGroupMembers.Members)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Email Address: {0}", address);
}
```

But how can I modify/create distribution group?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create Distribution Groups using EWS you can only create Contact Groups in a Mailbox or Public Folder. Distribution Groups are Mail Enabled Active Directory Groups (either distribution or security). Current the only API that is supported for creating these type of groups is the Exchange Management Shell cmdlets which you can use from Managed code eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff326159(v=exchg.140).aspx

Comment: Ok.
So I need to create Active Directory group instead using EWS?
If yes, I can to add an external user to this Distribution list?
Thanks!

Comment: No EWS is a User API for accessing Mailboxes so you cannot create an AD Group,User or contact using EWS or add and remove users from AD groups. You need to use a different API

Comment: Which API i can use instead?

Comment: The only supported API that can be used to create a Mail Enabled group is the Exchange Management Shell which you can use from Managed code I posted i link in the answer.