# How do you use exchangelib (or another python package) to create an Exchange distribution list?

Tags: python, exchange-server, exchangelib

I'm looking at [exchangelib](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib) and the [various](https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/exchangelib/properties.html#exchangelib.properties.DLMailbox) [docs](https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/) studying for a solution to create distribution lists programmatically.  I see mention of a DLMailbox class, but no guidance as to how to create a DL.  Pointers appreciated!  Thanks

208_man

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Group (Distribution group) and add members EWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979693/create-group-distribution-group-and-add-members-ews)

Comment: Thank you @ErikCederstrand, but I'm not sure what to do with that SO post. Do I need to create a mail enabled AD Group?  IS that the conclusion of that reference?

Comment: Is anything unclear in the accepted  answer to that question?

Comment: yes @ErikCederstrand.  Two things: 1) Is the 'answer' to 'how to create create a DL' to actually create a mail-enabled AD group? 2) Is there a solution that uses Python, JavaScript, PowerShell or Ruby? (instead of C#)

Comment: Yes, I believe a distribution list *is* a mail-enabled distribution group. exchangelib uses EWS which, as the SO answer explains, does not support creating such a group. Exchange (and AD) has a comprehensive PowerShell interface, so it may be possible to create a group that way.